# Is it possible to check the integrity of data encrypted using AES?

Tags: encryption, aes, man-in-the-middle

I am encrypting my payload using AES, before sending it over a TCP connection. Is it possible to verify whether it has been modified during transit by someone who doesn't have access to the shared key?

To expand, does this make sense?

Before sending:

1) Generate SHA256 hash from payload -> payload hash

2) Generate SHA256 hash from payload hash + shared secret -> final hash

On payload receive repeat above steps and compare hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to generate a HMAC function. Please use a HMAC function that uses SHA-256 instead. Please use a HMAC over the ciphertext, or you may be vulnerable to padding oracle attacks. It's best practice to use separate MAC & encryption keys, but for HMAC you can probably get away with a single key.

Note that the default method of transport layer encryption should be TLS, which already incorporates integrity & authenticity plus nice things like entity authentication, session key establishment, perfect forwarding secrecy, well studied protocols and algorithms etc. etc.

Comment: OK, secrecy got translated in my head to frequency, I'm heading for bed :)

Comment: Doesn't TLS require the use of PKI? The clients for my application will be entities without any digital certificates.

Comment: TLS and PKI are separate issues. Clients do not need certificates for TLS to be effective. (TLS is the new name for what was SSL; think HTTPS.)

Comment: Depends on the implementation, but the protocol can use [pre-shared keys (PSK)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4279). Otherwise you can cheat by using self signed certificates, possibly using the same certificate / private key.

Comment: And to the point of "think HTTPS," if you possibly can, I recommend converting "over TCP" to "over HTTPS." There are many reasons not to use HTTPS (mostly due to overhead), but it is extremely well supported and solves many problems in one stroke even if the implementor isn't an expert.

Comment: So in short, HTTPS will provide data integrity and proof that data was not tampered with right? I will encrypt the payload using AES to provide secrecy. Will this work if both clients have the same self-signed certificate?

Comment: HTTPS will also encrypt on the wire (provide secrecy), so there is seldom reason to use AES over HTTPS. Are you saying that clients are talking to clients? If so, then authentication is tricky (since they each need a way to trust that the other is who they say they are). If that isn't an issue, then you only need one certificate to secure an HTTPS channel.

Comment: Rather than thinking "self signed," I recommend thinking "pinned certificate." If you're talking to a single server, then the client can include that one public key and only trust that one public key. This is more secure than a commercial cert. But it depends on the details of your situation.